# Best way to mass enable / disable products (probably sql?)

Tags: product, products-management

I need to add several products with different categories in a magento store and leave them disabled. After certain date, I need to enable all of them and disable current enabled product.

My first thought is to:
Add special name int prodcut name, for instance:

- sp1-Donut
- sp1-Coffee
- sp1-Tea

afterwards select all items via sql and set their status on disabled

select all items that contain sp1 and enable those.

Would there be another option in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi fran35 and welcome to MageOverflow!

What about just using the mass edit feature of the product grid? Or do you want to do it automatically?

On stackoverflow is a great post how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365562/1480397

Comment: hello Fabian, thanks for the suggestion. Mass edit worked wonders on a short test, hopefully magento won't choke when in production (about 6000 products on current store). Regards!

Comment: As long as you increase `max_input_vars` high enough, I don't see a problem.